# Unity | Interactable Item: Change from Pickup on Collision to Pickup on Button Press

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am VERY new to C# and am going through a walk through tutorial on an Inventory system. I've gone into the input manager and I've got my 'E' button set as "Action".

In this tutorial, at the end on the Inventory code, we've set it up to pickup the item in front of us by walking over it and it is automatically placed into our inventory.

I'm trying to change this to pick up by pressing 'E' or my Action button. Is this feasible? Here is the code:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.GetComponent<Item>())
            AddItem(col.GetComponent<Item>());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple thing you can do is use both "OnTriggerEnter" and "OnTriggerExit" events to set and unset an instance variable. Then you can check input and the variable in the update method something like this

```
public class Player:MonoBehaviour{
  Item itemInContact;

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update()
  { 
      // If you can stand over several items iterate the list and add them all
      if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && itemInContact != null)
          AddItem(itemInContact);
  }

  private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
  {
      // If you can stand over several items you can use a list and push all the items
      if (col.GetComponent<Item>())
          itemInContact = col.GetComponent<Item>();
  }

  private void OnTriggerExit(Collider col)
  {
      // If you can stand over several items you should flush the list here
      itemInContact = null;
  }

  private void AddItem() { // Your addItemCode}
}
```

I hope this helps!